# Does characterEncoding in connection string set how values is stored?

Tags: mysql, grails, jdbc, character-encoding

I'm about to change the encoding for a database from latin1 to utf8mb4. 
Due to privacy restrictions, I don't know what the database to be converted contains. I'm worried that by running below SQL, existing data may be changed.

`ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

However, the connection string from the grails application contains **useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8**, does this mean that even though latin1_swedish_ci is used for a column, the actual value that has been saved is UTF-8 encoded?

And since this value is UTF-8 encoded, there is no risk that the data will be affected by the change from latin1 to utf8mb4?

````
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value             |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8              |
| character_set_connection | utf8              |
| character_set_database   | latin1            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary            |
| character_set_results    | utf8              |
| character_set_server     | latin1            |
| character_set_system     | utf8              |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci |
+--------------------------+-------------------+```
````

Comment: "does this mean that even though latin1_swedish_ci is used for a column, the actual value that has been saved is UTF-8 encoded?" - No. There are lots of SO questions asking why values like `Ώπα` get stored in the database as `???` when the column character set is latin1 (or similar). The connection string parameters tell the server that the string being sent is Unicode (encoded as UTF-8), but the latin1 character set does not include those characters so they are converted to question marks when they are written to the column.

Comment: Thank you for answering. When trying to insert characters not supported by latin1, through the application interface, the application returns an error message saying **"Incorrect string value: '\xCE\x8F\xCF\x80\xCE\xB1"** . This makes me feel surer that characters not supported by latin1 never have ended up in the database as question marks. Would this change the answer to the question you're answering?

Comment: The essential point is the same: If a column is defined as latin1 then it will only contain latin1-encoded strings. Converting a column from latin1 to utf8mb4 may change the *encoding* of the string but not it's value, e.g., 'André' will remain 'André' even if the 'é' is encoded differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `Ώπα`?  That's the interpretation in `UTF-8` (as the outside world calls it), `utf8mb4` (MySQL's equivalent) or `utf8` (MySQL's partial implementation of UTF-8).

It would not work well in `latin1`.

The encoding in the client and the encoding of a column in the database need not be the same.  However, Greek in the client cannot be crammed into latin1 in the table, hence the error message.

What `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` does is to change all the text columns in that table to be utf8-encoded *and* convert from whatever encoding is currently used (presumably latin1).  This is fine for Western European characters, all of which exist (with different encodings) in both latin1 and utf8.

To handle Emoji and some of Chinese, you may as well go for `utf8mb4`:

```
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried to write every possible character before converting, and could convert successfully without corrupting the data